# Copyrights regarding world maps

Tags: copyright, legal, maps

I am doing some freelance work for a client and she has asked me to illustrate a map visualising Africa and Europe.

She is including the illustration into a book she is writing in the hopes of eventually publishing it.

Is it okay if i base my illustration on open source maps or do i need to purchase stock images instead?

Any advice would be appreciated, Thanks!

Comment: Where are you getting the "open source" maps? Do they have any fine print associated with them which explains what license the creator has given?

Answer (score 1):

You should be alright using open source map images but as it was mentioned in the comment section, always verify the terms to see how and where you can use the design.

Additionally, you can always use the Wikipedia SVG maps that are in vectors, modify them as you want and add your own style to them. They are "public domain" and you can get pretty much any map you want there!

Comment: Not all images on Wikipedia are public domain. Some may require attribution, for example. You need to read the actual license associated with the image.